# Under what circumstances is equality of equalities decidable?

Tags: coq

Consider the following goals:

```
Goal forall (x y: I = I), x = y.
Proof.
Abort.

Goal forall (x y: tt = tt), x = y.
Proof.
Abort.
```

Both `I` and `tt` are members of singleton types. The former lives in `Prop`, the latter in `Set`. These are very uncomplicated types, so I wouldn't expect them to support rich equality types in any setting. Are these goals provable in Coq without resorting to the Uniqueness of Identity Proofs axiom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A common sufficient condition is for the type to have decidable equality; see also this FAQ: https://github.com/coq/coq/wiki/The-Logic-of-Coq#i-have-two-proofs-of-an-equality-statement-can-i-prove-they-are-equal